# How to distribute a web application to be run locally?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, local-storage, local

I would like to make a choose-your-own-adventure type of game, and since the game consists only of formatted text with images, I think it makes sense to make it with HTML/CSS and Javascript. However I don't want to maintain a web server, what I'd like to do is give the game to the users for them to run locally.

I don't have much (if any) experience in web development, so this is probably a naive question, but I couldn't find how to do it (search results were polluted with something called "serverless" which --- if I understand correctly --- is a web development paradigm that relies on the use of many servers).

The difficulty is in saving the player's progression which poses the following problems:

- it seems that the user has to run a local web server for local storage to work. When I play local web games (e.g. Twine games) I usually run `python -m http.server` in the game's folder, but I'd rather not assume all users know how to do that.
- I don't know how to make the stored data specific to my application: local storage is tied to the domain, so if the app is served on `localhost:8888` for instance, there is a risk that other apps served on the same port could access it and overwrite it by accident.

Comment: Hi there alternativeTouches! Great question, though I have a few recommendations to make sure you get the best answers possible here on SO. First, your context is great, but the content of your question doesn't quite match the title. Second, you seem to have two separate questions here. I'd recommend breaking this into two posts, each with a good title and one question each. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ElectronJs https://www.electronjs.org/ for example. (Read this https://www.reddit.com/r/incremental_games/comments/6zfs4z/electronbased_games/ for more informations). And good luck in your Game creator journey !

Comment: (With the caveat that if anything goes *wrong* in Electron without a fairly strong understanding of what's happening on both the web and native side, things can go *really* wrong.)